# How do I say the possessive, when three people possess the same item?

Tags: grammar

If two people possess the same item, the speaker would put an `'s` after the second name only. So, the storyteller would say

> Dudley and **Harry's** home is located at 4 Privet Drive.

If a pronoun is used, the speaker would use the possessive form for both. So, Dudley would say

> **Harry's and my home** is located at 4 Privet Drive.

My question is, how about three people? For example, how would Hedwig (Harry's friend, lives with Harry) refer to that house

> **Dudley's**, Harry's and my home is located at 4 Privet Drive.

or

> **Dudley**, Harry's and my home is located at 4 Privet Drive.

Comment: If anything you do is awkward, just rephrase the sentence. *The home **belonging to Harry, Dudley, and myself** is located at 4 Privet Drive.*